# Multivariate normal density function of function of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance, matrix-rank

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables and $g$ be a symmetric function such that $$g(X_i,X_j)\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$ for all $1\le i<j\le n$. I wish to know the density function of the joint random variable
$$Z=\left(g(X_1,X_2),g(X_1,X_3),\dots,g(X_{n-1},X_{n})\right)$$ which lies in ${n\choose 2}$-dimensional space. To do this, I assume that $Z$ follows multivariate normal distribution. However, the problem is that the covariance matrix $C$ of $Z$ is singular. Could anyone help me? Any advice or suggestion?

Comment: If the covariance matrix is singular, then the multivariate normal distribution is degenerate and does not have a density w.r.t. the corresponding Lebesgue measure. You could define its density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on the subspace containing the distribution's support (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Degenerate_case).

Comment: If I answer this, I'll probably say how to find $\operatorname{E}(Z) \in \mathbb R^{\binom n 2}$ and $C = \operatorname{var}(Z) \in \mathbb R^{\binom n 2 \times\binom n 2}$ and then let others worry about the actual _density_ if they want to. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So part of the question would be this: For which symmetric functions and which distributions of $X_1$ would $Z$ have a multivariate normal distribution? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I suspect one can show that no generality would be lost by assuming $X_1$ is normally distributed.  If so, then for which symmetric functions $g$ would it be the case that all of $g(X_i,X_j)$ are normally distributed?  Clearly it's true if $g(u,v) = a(u+v)$.  I wonder if one can eliminate all other possibilities? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If $n\ge 4$ then $\det C=0$ but otherwise $\det C>1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Budenn: Thanks for your response. So, how can I define the density w.r.t. that subspace containing the distribution's support?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for your comments. However, the random variables $X_i$'s are not necessary to be univariate. They even can be high dimensional vectors but every pair of them is transformed to a real number via the function $g$.

Comment: @Jlamprong For mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$ the subspace is $\{ \mu + \Sigma^{1/2} v | v \in R^{\binom{n}{2}}\}$, and the density is $f_Z(z) = (\det^* (2 \pi \Sigma))^{-1/2} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (z - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-} (z - \mu)\right)$, where $\det^*$ is the [pseudo-determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-determinant)(product of non-zero eigenvalues) and $\Sigma^-$ is the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $\Sigma$.

Comment: @Jlamprong : I don't think the fact that $X_i$ is not necessarily univariate alters my comment that probably no generality would be lost by assuming $X_i$ is univariate normal.  Some function $J(X_i)$ would be univariate normal and then $K(J(X_i),J(X_j))$ would be $g(X_i,X_j)$, so we could just as well work with $J(X_i)$ rather than with $X_i$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I am not sure if it valied for every function $g$. For instance, suppose that $X_i\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $g$ is defined by $g(x,y)=<x,y>$ the usual inner product. How would we take the function $J$?

Answer (score 2):

See my comments under the question.  What I write below will assume my guesses there are right and that $a=1$.

Your symmetric matrix $C$ will have one row corresponding to each unordered pair $\{i,j\}$.

The entry in row $\{i,j\}$ and column $\{k,\ell\}$ will be $2$ if $\{i,j\}=\{k,\ell\}$.  Those are just the diagonal entries in the matrix.  In row $\{i,j\}$, there will be a $1$ in each column $\{k,\ell\}$ for which $|\{i,j\}\cap\{k,\ell\}| = 1$, and there are $2n-3$ such columns. The remaining $\dbinom{n-2} 2$ such columns in that row will contain a $0$.  This is a $\dbinom n 2 \times \dbinom n 2$ matrix of rank $n$.  It can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix and then you have the $n$ nonzero eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Software is telling me that when $n=5$ then the eigenvalues are
$8,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0$ and when $n=6$ they are $10,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0$.  When $n=7$ they are $12,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,\ldots,0$ ($21$ of them).  Here one can guess that the largest eigenvalue is $2(n-1)$ and the next $n-1$ of them are $n-2$, and clearly the rest have to be $0$.  The sum of the eigenvalues would then be $n(n-1)$.

**P.S.:** I have [confirmed my guess about the eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380302/diagonalizing-a-matrix-arising-in-a-simple-combinatorial-situation/1380613#1380613).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think, in this special case, we can obtain the density function by formula as gien by @Budenn. However, how about my above question?