# Symmetric function of two normal distribution implies bilinear

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, normal-distribution

This question is related to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380227/multivariate-normal-density-function-of-function-of-random-variable) which was partially answered my @MichaelHardy.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent standard normal random variables. Now, suppose that $g:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a symmetric smooth function such that $g(X,Y)$ is normally distributed. Intuitively, $g$ should be in the form $g(X,Y)=a(X+Y)+b$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ since the other "algebraic operations" except sum will never give normal distribution again. However, how will we prove this conjecture precisely?

Comment: With symmetric you mean that $g(x,y)=g(y,x)$, right?

Comment: @Bernhard: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your assertion is not correct. Take the following example:

The product $X\cdot Y$ has a product normal distribution with cumulative distribution function $F_{PN}$. Hence, as a consequence, $F_{PN}(X\cdot Y)$ has a uniform distribution by the [Inverse Transform Sampling Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). Similarly, if $Z$ has normal distribution with cumulative distribution function $F_N$, then $F_N(Z)$ has a uniform distribution. Hence, $F_N^{-1}(F_{PN}(X\cdot Y))$ has normal distribution, too.